# When asynchronous tasks make a bad UX

Tags: concurrency, user-interface, user-experience, asynchronous-programming

I'm writing a COM add-in that's extending an IDE that desperately needs it. There are many features involved, but let's narrow it down to 2 for the sake of this post:

- There's a *Code Explorer* toolwindow that displays a *treeview* that lets the user navigate modules and their members.
- There's a *Code Inspections* toolwindow that displays a *datagridview* that lets the user navigate code issues and automatically fix them.

Both tools have a "Refresh" button that starts an asynchronous task that parses all the code in all opened projects; the *Code Explorer* uses the parse results to build the *treeview*, and the *Code Inspections* uses the parse results to find code issues and display the results in its *datagridview*.

What I'm trying to do here, is to share the parse results between features, so that when the *Code Explorer* refreshes, then the *Code Inspections* knows about it and can refresh itself without having to redo the parsing work that the *Code Explorer* just did.

So what I did, I made my parser class an event provider that the features can register to:

```
    private void _parser_ParseCompleted(object sender, ParseCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
        {
            Control.SolutionTree.Nodes.Clear();
            foreach (var result in e.ParseResults)
            {
                var node = new TreeNode(result.Project.Name);
                node.ImageKey = "Hourglass";
                node.SelectedImageKey = node.ImageKey;

                AddProjectNodes(result, node);
                Control.SolutionTree.Nodes.Add(node);
            }
            Control.EnableRefresh();
        });
    }

    private void _parser_ParseStarted(object sender, ParseStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
        {
            Control.EnableRefresh(false);
            Control.SolutionTree.Nodes.Clear();
            foreach (var name in e.ProjectNames)
            {
                var node = new TreeNode(name + " (parsing...)");
                node.ImageKey = "Hourglass";
                node.SelectedImageKey = node.ImageKey;

                Control.SolutionTree.Nodes.Add(node);
            }
        });
    }
```

And it works. The problem I'm having, is that... it works - I mean, when the code inspections get refreshed, the parser tells the code explorer (and everyone else) "dude, someone's parsing, anything you want to do about it?" - and when parsing completes, the parser tells its listeners "guys, I have fresh parse results for you, anything you want to do about it?".

Let me walk you through an example to illustrate the problem this creates:

- User brings up the Code Explorer, which tells the user "hold on, I'm working here"; user continues to work in the IDE, the Code Explorer redraws itself, life is beautiful.
- User then brings up the Code Inspections, which tell the user "hold on, I'm working here"; the parser tells the Code Explorer "dude, someone's parsing, anything you want to do about it?" - the Code Explorer tells the user "hold on, I'm working here"; user can still work in the IDE, but can't navigate the Code Explorer because it's refreshing. And he's waiting for the code inspections to complete, too.
- User sees a code issue in the inspection results they want to address; they double-click to navigate to it, confirm there's an issue with the code, and click the "Fix" button. The module was modified and needs to be re-parsed, so the code inspections proceed with it; the Code Explorer tells the user "hold on, I'm working here", ...

See where this is going? I don't like it, and I bet users won't like it either. What am I missing? How should I go about sharing parse results between features, but still leave the user in control of when the feature should *do its work*?

The reason I'm asking, is because I figured that if I postponed the actual work until the user actively decides to refresh, and "cached" the parse results as they come in... well then I'd be refreshing a treeview and locating code issues in a possibly stale parse result... which literally brings me back to square one, where each feature works with its own parse results: is there any way I can share parse results between features *and* have a lovely UX?

The code is [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), but I'm not looking for code, I'm looking for *concepts*.

Comment: Just an FYI, we also have a [UserExperience.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) site as well. I believe this is on-topic here because it is discussing _code design_ more than _user interface_ but I wanted to let you know in case your changes drift more toward the UI side and not the code/design side of the issue.

Comment: When you are parsing, is this an all-or-nothing operation? For example: does a change in a file trigger a complete reparse, or only for that file and those that depend on it?

Comment: @Morgen there's two things: `VBAParser` is generated by ANTLR and gives me a parse tree, but the features don't consume that. The `RubberduckParser` takes the parse tree, walks it, and issues a `VBProjectParseResult` that contains `Declaration` objects that have all their `References` resolved - *that's* what the features take for input.. so yeah, it's pretty much an all-or-nothing situation. The `RubberduckParser` is smart enough to not re-parse modules that have not been modified though. But if there's a bottleneck it's not the with the parsing, it's with the code inspections.

Comment: Basically I can't resolve references until I have an entire project completely parsed (and in future versions I want to account for inter-project references too - which means I'll have to parse all projects before I can start resolving references), so I can't issue parse results module by module as they complete, my features wouldn't know what to do with those ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for the clarification. What are the ramifications of stale results? Can stale results be accommodated, ex: using a quick local search to get the correct line for a function that has been moved up/down a few lines?

Comment: hmm I'm using the token's position to locate it in the code module, that would entail additional logic... and what if last action was a refactoring that changed the name of the function we're trying to locate? things get very complicated very fast! ;)

Comment: I think, I would do it like this: When the user triggers a refresh, that toolwindow triggers the parse and shows that it's working. The other toolwindow(s) are not notified yet, they keep displaying the old information. Until the parser finishes. At that point, the parser would signal all toolwindows to refresh their view with the new information. Should the user go to another toolwindow while the parser is working, that window would also enter the "working..." state and signal a reparse. The parser would then start over to deliver up-to-date info to all windows at the same time.

Comment: One of the great things about Antlr is that it allows you to create multiple different kinds of parsers/listeners/visitors. Perhaps what is called for here is a specialized parser solely for the Code Explorer. Another, more general purpose parser for the other features? I've not thought it through exactly. More just a passing thought.

Comment: @cmaster I would upvote that comment as an answer too.

Comment: @RubberDuck that would work, if the code explorer was just a treeview. But its context menu requires passing in the resolved `Declaration`  for *rename* and *find all references* to play nicely with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way that I would probably approach this would be to focus less on providing perfect results, and instead focus on a best-effort approach. This would result in at least the following changes:

- Convert the logic that currently starts a re-parse to request instead of initiate.

  The logic for requesting a re-parse may end up looking something like this:

  ```
  IF parseIsRunning IS false
    startParsingThread()
  ELSE
    SET shouldParse TO true
  END
  ```

  This will be paired with logic wrapping the parser, that may look something like this:

  ```
  SET parseIsRunning TO true
  DO 
    SET shouldParse TO false
    doParsing()
  WHILE shouldParse IS true
  SET parseIsRunning TO false
  ```

  The important thing is that the parser run until the most recent re-parse request has been honored, but no more than one parser is running at any given time.
- Remove the `ParseStarted` callback. Requesting a re-parse is now a fire and forget operation.

  Alternately, convert it to do nothing other than show a refreshing indicator in some out of the way part of the GUI that does not block user interaction.
- Try to provide minimal handling for stale results.

  In the case of the Code Explorer, that may be as simple as looking a reasonable number of lines up and down for a method the user wants to navigate to, or the nearest method if an exact name wasn't found.

  I'm not sure what would be appropriate for the Code Inspector.

I'm not sure of the implementation details, but overall, this is very similar to how the NetBeans editor handles this behavior. It is always very quick to point out that it's currently refreshing, but also does not block access to the functionality.

Stale results are often good enough - especially when compared to no results.

Comment: Excellent points, but I have a question: I'm using `ParseStarted` to disable the [Refresh] button (`Control.EnableRefresh(false)`). If I remove that callback, and let the user click it... then I'd put myself in a situation where I have two concurrent tasks doing the parsing... how do I avoid this without disabling refresh on all other functionalities while someone is parsing?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I updated my answer to include that facet of the problem.

Comment: I agree with this approach, except that I would still keep a `ParseStarted` event, in case you do want to allow the UI (or other component) to sometimes warn the user a reparse is occurring. Of course, you may want to document callers should attempt to _not_ stop the user from using the (about to be) stale current parse results.